# Codeigniter navigation doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I made a new application with just 2 views in application/views and 1 controller. I just want to go from page1 in view to page2 in view via the controller.

here is the whole code:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cytt5azgerrbsg2/Afstudeerproject.zip?dl=0

### Relevant Code

view 1:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
             <h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter!</h1>
             <div id="body">
                 <?= form_open(site_url('Welcome/steven')) ?>
                <input type="file" name="userfile" />
                <p><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" /></p>
                <?= form_close() ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

view 2:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
             <h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter!</h1>
             <div id="body">
                <?= form_open(site_url('welcome')) ?>
                <input type="file" name="userfile" />
                <p><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" /></p>
                <?= form_close() ?>
             </div>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
     }
    public function steven() {
        $this->load->view('welcome_secondpage');
    }
}
```

routes.php:

```
 $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
 $route['404_override'] = '';
 $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

config.php:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

autoload.php:

```
 $autoload['helper'] = array('form' , 'url');
```

the rest of the files are all standard CodeIgnitor

Comment: Could you post the relevant code to StackOverflow? I don't feel safe downloading random zip files from the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your config file assign this `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`

Comment: how weird. Tried that like 10 times, but it works. Thanks !